# SQL: Determine time spent at locations (Snowflake)

Tags: sql, location, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, latitude-longitude

I want to determine time spent at locations when an object is at a location that repeats.  Any ideas how to derive that from this data sample using three ObjectID over two days?  Thx

| ObjectID | DateTime | Lat | Lon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 5/2/2021 12:00 | 40.11 | -30.34 |
| 23 | 5/2/2021 16:00 | 40.11 | -30.34 |
| 23 | 5/2/2021 23:00 | 40.11 | -30.34 |
| 23 | 5/3/2021 12:00 | 40.11 | -30.34 |
| 23 | 5/3/2021 16:00 | 39.88 | -29.00 |
| 23 | 5/3/2021 23:00 | 40.11 | -30.34 |
| 24 | 5/2/2021 12:00 | 40.11 | -30.34 |
| 24 | 5/2/2021 16:00 | 40.11 | -30.34 |
| 24 | 5/2/2021 23:00 | 39.88 | -29.00 |
| 24 | 5/3/2021 12:00 | 39.88 | -29.00 |
| 24 | 5/3/2021 16:00 | 40.11 | -30.34 |
| 24 | 5/3/2021 23:00 | 39.88 | -29.00 |
| 25 | 5/2/2021 12:00 | 40.11 | -30.34 |
| 25 | 5/2/2021 16:00 | 39.88 | -29.00 |
| 25 | 5/2/2021 23:00 | 40.11 | -30.34 |
| 25 | 5/3/2021 12:00 | 39.88 | -29.00 |
| 25 | 5/3/2021 16:00 | 40.11 | -30.34 |
| 25 | 5/3/2021 23:00 | 40.11 | -30.34 |

Desired Output shoule be the ObjectID, the earliest DateTime in the location, and the Time in that location:

| ObjectID | StartingDateTime | Lat | Lon | TimeInLocation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 5/2/2021 12:00 | 40.11 | -30.34 | 24:00:00 |
| 24 | 5/2/2021 12:00 | 40.11 | -30.34 | 04:00:00 |
| 24 | 5/2/2021 23:00 | 39.88 | -29.00 | 13:00:00 |
| 25 | 5/3/2021 16:00 | 40.11 | -30.34 | 07:00:00 |

ObjectID 23 was in the same location from 5/2 12:00-5/3 12:00, so one row is returned showing 24 hours

ObjectID 24 was in the same location twice:

- 5/2 12:00-5/2 16:00, so one row is returned showing 4 hours
- 5/2 23:00-5/3 12:00, so another row is returned showing 13 hours

ObjectID 25 was in the same location from 5/3 16:00-5/3 23:00, so one row is returned showing 7 hours

Comment: I'm lost.  Where was the object 23 between 5/3/2021 12:00 and 5/3/2021 16:00 and between 5/3/2021 16:00 and 5/3/2021 23:00?

Comment: @GordonLinoff : data is collected at random times, not at arrival or departure.  Therefore, we do not know where object 23 was between 5/3 12:00 and 5/3 16:00.  We could assume it spent some time at the location we want to calculate the TimeInLocation for, and some in travel, but the data does not confirm that.
My real data will typically reflect multiple LAT/LON locations in travel.  I did not show that in the sample to reduce # of rows, in an attempt to make the data easier to understand. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem, if I follow correctly.  You can get the positions with more than one row using a difference of row numbers:

```
select objectid, lat, lon,
       timestampdiff(second, max(datetime), min(datetime))
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by objectid, lat, lon order by datetime) as seqnum_2,
             row_number() over (partition by objectid order by datetime) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by objectid, (seqnum - seqnum_2), lat, lon
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks- this seems to return exactly what I need.
For anyone else reading this, the "-" operator did not work for me in Snowflake, so I replaced the 1st line of Gordon's code with this:     
   -   select objectid, lat, lon, min(datetime), TIMESTAMPDIFF('second', max(datetime), min(datetime))